# Three way comparison replaces all others comparison operators except ==?

Tags: c++, c++20, spaceship-operator

In g++ 10, I am trying to use three way comparison, just for experiment.

I read that other operators do not needed anymore (except ==).

But even if I can use operator (it is implemented on the compiler), it does not supersede (or imply) !=.

So, the following code does not work.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    struct Iterator
    {
        size_t index;
        size_t operator*() { return index + 1000; }
        //bool operator!=(const Iterator &a) const { return index != a.index; }
        auto operator<=>(const Iterator &a) const { return index <=> a.index; }
        Iterator &operator++() { ++index; return *this; }
    };
    Iterator begin() { return Iterator{0}; }
    Iterator end() { return Iterator{5}; }
};


int main()
{
    A a;
    auto result = a.begin() <=> a.end();
    for (auto b : a)
        cout << b << "\n";
    cout << (a.begin() != a.end()) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you aware, that you are always returning a new object in `begin` and `end` functions?

Comment: @NutCracker Yep. For such a small object it is not a deal.

Comment: @NutCracker Iterators are supposed to be lightweight and returning by value is how `begin()` and `end()` are usually implemented.

Comment: @Chameleon I believe you need to include `<compare>` too. Otherwise the program is ill-formed if I understand the spec. correctly ... or maybe not ... I got stuck here: http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.spaceship#9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons):

> In brief, a class that defines `operator<=>` automatically gets compiler-generated operators **<**, **<=**, **>**, and **>=**. A class can define `operator<=>` as defaulted, in which case the compiler will also generate the code for that operator."

The code for != and == is not generated, thus you do need to implement the comparisons.

Answer (score 9):

> I read that other operators do not needed anymore (except ==).

Right, *except* `==` is the key bit. There are two categories of comparison operators:

- equality operators (`==`, `!=`)
- ordering operators (`<=>`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`)

In each of those categories, the first one I listed (`==` and `<=>`) is the *primary* comparison operator. It is the only operator that you need to define if you want to opt in to that category. If you want equality, provide `==`. If you want ordering, provide `<=>` (and also `==`). The other comparison operators are *secondary* comparison operators - expressions using secondary comparison are, in C++20, rewritten to use the primary comparison operator.

These categories are completely distinct<sup>†</sup> - there is no crossover. A `x != y` expression can invoke `operator==(x, y)` or even `operator==(y, x)` but it will never invoke an `operator<=>` of any kind.

You have code that requires an equality comparison but don't have the equality operator defined, hence it's ill-formed. To get this to work, you need to add:

```
bool operator==(const Iterator &a) const { return index == a.index; }
auto operator<=>(const Iterator &a) const { return index <=> a.index; }
```

Note `==`, not `!=`. You should not declare secondary comparison operators in C++20, unless you have a very specific need for them (and this is not such a need).

For more, see [Comparisons in C++20](https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2019/07/28/comparisons-cpp20/).

---

<sup>†</sup>The single exception to this rule is, for convenience, if you *default* `operator<=>` then you *also* get a declared, defaulted `operator==`. It's as if you had defaulted both yourself. In this example, since your comparisons are just the default member-wise comparisons, you could have written:

```
auto operator<=>(const Iterator &a) const = default;
```

As your single comparison operator declaration, which would've behaved as if you'd written:

```
bool operator==(const Iterator &a) const = default;
auto operator<=>(const Iterator &a) const = default;
```

Which gives you the correct equality operator you need for your program.

Answer (score 1):

`operator ==` is implicitly declared as defaulted for each operator `operator <=>` defined as defaulted:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    struct Iterator
    {
        size_t index;
        size_t operator*() { return index + 1000; }
        //bool operator!=(const Iterator &a) const { return index != a.index; }

        auto operator<=>(const Iterator &) const = default;
        // bool operator == (const Iterator&) const; implicitly declared

        Iterator &operator++() { ++index; return *this; }
    };
    Iterator begin() { return Iterator{0}; }
    Iterator end() { return Iterator{5}; }
};


int main()
{
    A a;
    auto result = a.begin() <=> a.end();
    for (auto b : a)
        cout << b << "\n";
    cout << (a.begin() != a.end()) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```